# WSDL class error

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, soap, wsdl2apex

Good morning, I have a wsdl that I generated with salesforce, but when I call some methods I get this error:

> EXCEPTION_THROWN [157]|System.CalloutException: Web service callout
>   failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for
>   element =entry

the class that SFDC generate is:

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class serviceIdaCombaseCl2 {
    public class sendSmsO {
        public String in0;
        public String in1;
        public String in2;
        public String in3;
        public String in4;
        private String[] in0_type_info = new String[]{'in0','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in1_type_info = new String[]{'in1','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in2_type_info = new String[]{'in2','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in3_type_info = new String[]{'in3','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in4_type_info = new String[]{'in4','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'in0','in1','in2','in3','in4'};
    }
    public class sendSmsOResponse {
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.StringStringMap out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class getCarrierResponse {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class StringStringMap {
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.IdentifiedUser[] entry;
        private String[] entry_type_info = new String[]{'entry','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'entry'};
    }
    public class IdentifiedUser {
        public String key;
        public String value;
        private String[] key_type_info = new String[]{'key','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] value_type_info = new String[]{'value','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'key','value'};
    }
    public class getRecievedMessages {
        public String in0;
        public String in1;
        private String[] in0_type_info = new String[]{'in0','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in1_type_info = new String[]{'in1','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'in0','in1'};
    }
    public class sendSmsResponse {
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.StringStringMap out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class sendSms {
        public String in0;
        public String in1;
        public String in2;
        public String in3;
        private String[] in0_type_info = new String[]{'in0','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in1_type_info = new String[]{'in1','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in2_type_info = new String[]{'in2','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in3_type_info = new String[]{'in3','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'in0','in1','in2','in3'};
    }
    public class getRecievedMessagesResponse {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class smsStatus {
        public String in0;
        public String in1;
        public String in2;
        private String[] in0_type_info = new String[]{'in0','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in1_type_info = new String[]{'in1','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in2_type_info = new String[]{'in2','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'in0','in1','in2'};
    }
    public class getCredits {
        public String in0;
        public String in1;
        private String[] in0_type_info = new String[]{'in0','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in1_type_info = new String[]{'in1','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'in0','in1'};
    }
    public class getCarrier {
        public String in0;
        public String in1;
        public String in2;
        private String[] in0_type_info = new String[]{'in0','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in1_type_info = new String[]{'in1','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] in2_type_info = new String[]{'in2','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'in0','in1','in2'};
    }
    public class getCreditsResponse {
        public String out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class smsStatusResponse {
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.StringStringMap out;
        private String[] out_type_info = new String[]{'out','http://service.ida.combase.cl/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'out'};
    }
    public class SmsApiManagerImplPort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://ida.itdchile.cl/services/smsApiService';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://service.ida.combase.cl/', 'serviceIdaCombaseCl2'};
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.StringStringMap sendSms(String in0,String in1,String in2,String in3) {
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSms request_x = new serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSms();
            request_x.in0 = in0;
            request_x.in1 = in1;
            request_x.in2 = in2;
            request_x.in3 = in3;
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsResponse response_x;
            Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'sendSms',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'sendSmsResponse',
              'serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.StringStringMap smsStatus(String in0,String in1,String in2) {
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.smsStatus request_x = new serviceIdaCombaseCl2.smsStatus();
            request_x.in0 = in0;
            request_x.in1 = in1;
            request_x.in2 = in2;
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.smsStatusResponse response_x;
            Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.smsStatusResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.smsStatusResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'smsStatus',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'smsStatusResponse',
              'serviceIdaCombaseCl2.smsStatusResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
        public serviceIdaCombaseCl2.StringStringMap sendSmsO(String in0,String in1,String in2,String in3,String in4) {
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsO request_x = new serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsO();
            request_x.in0 = in0;
            request_x.in1 = in1;
            request_x.in2 = in2;
            request_x.in3 = in3;
            request_x.in4 = in4;
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsOResponse response_x;
            Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsOResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsOResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'sendSmsO',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'sendSmsOResponse',
              'serviceIdaCombaseCl2.sendSmsOResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
        public String getCarrier(String in0,String in1,String in2) {
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCarrier request_x = new serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCarrier();
            request_x.in0 = in0;
            request_x.in1 = in1;
            request_x.in2 = in2;
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCarrierResponse response_x;
            Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCarrierResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCarrierResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'getCarrier',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'getCarrierResponse',
              'serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCarrierResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
        public String getCredits(String in0,String in1) {
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCredits request_x = new serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCredits();
            request_x.in0 = in0;
            request_x.in1 = in1;
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCreditsResponse response_x;
            Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCreditsResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCreditsResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'getCredits',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'getCreditsResponse',
              'serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getCreditsResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
        public String getRecievedMessages(String in0,String in1) {
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getRecievedMessages request_x = new serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getRecievedMessages();
            request_x.in0 = in0;
            request_x.in1 = in1;
            serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getRecievedMessagesResponse response_x;
            Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getRecievedMessagesResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getRecievedMessagesResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'getRecievedMessages',
              'http://service.ida.combase.cl/',
              'getRecievedMessagesResponse',
              'serviceIdaCombaseCl2.getRecievedMessagesResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.out;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the response I get when I tried in SOAP UI:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:smsStatusResponse xmlns:ns1="http://service.ida.combase.cl/">
         <ns1:out>
            <entry>
               <key>MESSAGE</key>
               <value>CONFIRMED DELIVERY</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
               <key>DELIVERYDATE</key>
               <value>2018-06-14 13:46:30.0</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
               <key>STATUS</key>
               <value>OK</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
               <key>CODE</key>
               <value>0</value>
            </entry>
         </ns1:out>
      </ns1:smsStatusResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any one have a workaround about this error?

Comment: Can you share the WSDL that you generated the Apex from. I noticed in https://ida.itdchile.cl/services/smsApiService?wsdl that the `smsStatusResponse` was defined as `<soap:body use="literal"/>` rather than defining the `message` attribute for the type of the response.

Comment: I'd also expect `entry`, `key`, and `value` to have the `http://service.ida.combase.cl/` namespace in the response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an Entry object that needs to be defined, I would say to examine the response you get back  from the callout and se if you can identify the structure of the entry element and see if you can manually create it.  Maybe if you post the response you could probably get some help with it.

Comment: Hello @Gareth Jordan, thanks for you reply, I can't read the response because I get the error, but I tried in SOAP UI and I get this response: